# how to write output data into a text file iteratively?

Tags: python, string, pandas, encoding, gensim

I have a dataframe it looks like this :

```
id  created_at  text    month

0   911721027587231746  2017-09-23 22:36:46 تفاصيل استخدام سيارات الإسعاف لتهريب المواد ال...   9
1   911719688257851397  2017-09-23 22:31:27 تطوير لقاح جديد لمحاربة تسوس الأسنان\n https:/...   9
2   911715658395725826  2017-09-23 22:15:26 "حمدي الميرغني" يشارك جمهوره بصورة جديدة من شه...   9
3   911715466166587392  2017-09-23 22:14:40 شخصية مصر.. في عيون جمال حمدان (2) https://t.c...   9
```

month column has values that range from 1 to 11 and I want to build a model on the text data based on the number of the month and I'm trying to get the output and save it to a txt file but when I open the files I find it only contains one line each.

what I want is to get 11 text file each named per index and each one should contain 12 lines .

this is my code

```
def model(final_text):

    sentences = [clean(raw_sentence) for raw_sentence in final_text]
    doc_clean = [i.split() for i in sentences]
    dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(doc_clean)
    doc_term_matrix = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in doc_clean]
    Lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel
    ldamodel = Lda(doc_term_matrix, num_topics=12, id2word = dictionary, passes = 100, alpha='auto', update_every=5)
    x = ldamodel.print_topics(num_topics=12, num_words=5)

    y = ldamodel.show_topics(num_topics=12, num_words=5, formatted=False)
    topics_words = [(tp[0], [wd[0] for wd in tp[1]]) for tp in y]
    for topic,words in topics_words:
        #print(" ".join(words).encode('utf-8'))
        #print(words)

        f = open(str(i)+'.txt', 'wb')
        f.write(" ".join(words).encode('utf-8'))
        #f.write(words.encode('utf-8'))
    f.close()

#clean is just a function for cleaning data and it returns text

for i in range(1,12):
    df = parsed[parsed['month'] == i]
    text = df.text
    model(text)
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
for topic,words in topics_words:
    # print(" ".join(words).encode('utf-8'))
    # print(words)

    f = open(str(i)+'.txt', 'wb')
    f.write(" ".join(words).encode('utf-8'))
    # f.write(words.encode('utf-8'))
f.close()
```

You are closing the file after you go through the loop, so it is only saving the very last file. Change it to this:

```
for topic,words in topics_words:
    # print(" ".join(words).encode('utf-8'))
    # print(words)

    # f = open(str(i)+'.txt', 'wb')
    with open(str(i) + '.txt', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(" ".join(words).encode('utf-8'))
    # f.write(words.encode('utf-8'))
# f.close()
```

Opening the file with a "with statement" automatically closes it after it is done writing.

Also, where is "i" coming from in the filename, "str(i) + '.txt'"? If it is coming from the outside "for loop" you should add it as a parameter to the function. Don't use it as a global variable.

Comment: I is coming from the next loop where the function is called, I tried your code but still the same result

Comment: Thanks a lot I could solve it 
    with open(str(i)+'.txt', 'wb') as f:
         for topic,words in topics_words:
              f.write(" ".join(words).encode('utf-8'))

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(str(i)+'.txt', 'wb') as f:
    for topic,words in topics_words:
        f.write(" ".join(words).encode('utf-8'))
```

I opened the file first and ran the loop inside and the problem was solved